# ¿Como saber si existe una clave con un valor determinado en un arrayphp?

Tags: php

Tengo un array multidimensional como este en PHP:

```
$array = array(
    array("postre" => "helado","bebida" => "cafe"),
    array("postre" => "flan","bebida" => "soda")
);
```

Necesito saber si la clave "bebida" con el valor "soda" existe. ¿Como se hace esto?. Gracias!

Comment: ciclo foreach y buscas en la bebida y haces un condicional para saber si es soda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

También puede hacerlo con array_column y array_search

```
$array = array(
    array("postre" => "helado","bebida" => "cafe"),
    array("postre" => "flan","bebida" => "soda")
);

if ( false === array_search( 'soda', array_column($array, 'bebida') ) ) {
    echo 'no existe el valor: soda';
}  else { 
    echo 'si existe el valor: soda';
} 

// Resultado: si existe el valor: soda
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes utilizar [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php). Lo que hace es crear un array nuevo que contiene solamente los elementos que cumplen con un criterio X. Después podes contar la cantidad de elementos para saber cuántas coincidencias hubo.

Si solo te importa si hay al menos una coincidencia, tal vez sea más económico hacer un `foreach` y cortar en la primera coincidencia.

```
$array = [
    ['postre' => 'helado', 'bebida' => 'cafe'],
    ['postre' => 'flan', 'bebida' => 'soda'],
];

$matches = array_filter($array, function ($item) {
    return $item['bebida'] == 'soda';
});

echo count($matches);
```